# add identical data to one column for ALL rows (mySQL) via phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating my first (!) database, and I have run into an issue that I cannot seem to locate the answer for.

I have put an "added on" field in a table (among other things ofc), and since I'm the one adding it, I want to put the same date in the entire column. The idea is that if there is a new item added at a later date, it will have that date, but the data initially populated should all have the same date.

How? Please don't tell me one row at a time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility in addition to @Nicola's answer is to use the DEFAULT argument in add column.

Comment: Thank you- this will be how I set up the others. Much easier.

Comment: @mschocobo yes but be careful that if you use default this will be true also for newly generated rows

Comment: ... which is likely what you want, unless you override the value in code, in which case the default doesn't apply.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the column to the table and then run an update query

```
update yourtable set nameofyournewfield = 'yourdate'
```

This will  update all rows currently in the db, while the new rows will gettheir value (or have the default value you provided)

Answer (score 0):

You can set default property of that column to any date and it will replicate that for all rows as long as you don't specify any value for that column while inserting and when you want to insert a different value just specify it in the insert statement.